# How to subclass a subclass of UIViewController with xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, inheritance

I am working on a game. The game has different levels but share the same methods. I was thinking about subclassing the main game class.

How can i subclass the main game class(the main game class is a subclass of viewcontroller with xib)? Can i overrider the xib with subclass's xib?

```
//my main game class.
@interface Game : UIViewController{

//subclass
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
import "Game.h"

@interface level1 : Game {

}
```

when i used level1.view, it gave me an error"accessing unknown view class method)

It it is impossible, how can i create a game with different levels~~ thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> accessing unknown view class method

This looks like you are calling `[level1 view]`. This is an attempt to call a class method name `+view`. There is no such class method. You are attempting to get to an instance method name `-view`.

```
level1 *myLevel1 = [[level1 alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
myLevel1.view;
```

BTW: It is the usual practice to have a capital letter begin a class. So the class name should be `Level1` not `level1`.

Comment: I rewrote the code, it's working fine now. Thanks for your advice, BTW:i changed level1 to Level1~

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create layers on your view for each level.